# LottieView shuts down the app on android and works on IOS

Tags: android, react-native, expo, lottie

When using lottie in expo and react-native, all animations work on ios however crash the app on android. Is there something special for android I am missing?

I have created a new project and duplicated the issue by coping the code from the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/#__next)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.play();
    // Or set a specific startFrame and endFrame with:
    // this.animation.play(30, 120);
  }

  resetAnimation = () => {
    this.animation.reset();
    this.animation.play();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.animationContainer}>
        <LottieView
          ref={animation => {
            this.animation = animation;
          }}
          style={{
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            backgroundColor: '#eee',
          }}
          source={require('./assets/gradientBall.json')}
          // OR find more Lottie files @ https://lottiefiles.com/featured
          // Just click the one you like, place that file in the 'assets' folder to the left, and replace the above 'require' statement
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button title="Restart Animation" onPress={this.resetAnimation} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the Lottie dependency?

Comment: no do your know how i would go about that? Thanksssss!!!!

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Expo, you can't use Lottie 3 Files. From the expo api reference (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/):

"
Known Issues:
The Lottie SDK is currently considered to be under Expo's "DangerZone" because it's implementation is still in Alpha.

Importing Lottie 3 files causes the previewer to crash without a visible error, because Expo relies on lottie-react-native v2.
"

Answer (score 0):

Run Yarn add lottie-react-native@3.0.3 or npm install lottie-react-native@3.0.3